# get_the_category() wordpress function stopped working after updating core version

Tags: wordpress, categories

As the title says - i have a single.php template which gets the category of the current post assigned.

```
$cat_post = get_the_category();
```

That function returns the category which is assigned to the post. After upgrading from 4.0.24 to 4.9.7 it stopped working. The only thing that comes to my mind is that the function is not supported but i haven't found something about this.

Any ideas?

Comment: The function is supported. WordPress changelog doesn't indicate anything new and it's working fine for me. What happens when you var_dump $cat_post? Does it return an empty array?

Comment: @DerekNolan Yes it returns an empty array. `print_r(get_the_ID())` returns the post's ID. `get_the_category(get_the_ID());` also returns an empty array. The post is assigned to a category

Comment: okay.  Is it being used within a loop? Can you check that it’s not a custom taxonomy. Maybe have a look at get_the_terms https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
//get category 

$category   = get_the_category(get_the_ID());

//the above code will return an Array

Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 2
            [name] => video
            [slug] => video
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 2
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 2
            [category_count] => 1
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => video
            [category_nicename] => video
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

)

// you can access this array like this

$catID = $category[0]->term_id;
//for term id

$catName = $category[0]->name;
//for category name
```

Comment: `print_r(get_the_ID())` returns the post's ID.`get_the_category(get_the_ID());` returns an empty array. The post is assigned to a category though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get a category from the current post which is the custom post type.
As per the documentation of the following function, it doesn't work for the custom post type. You can see it on the link below.
[Click here to see the Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)

For custom post type, you can use get_the_terms() method. Here is the [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) of the Code Reference of the function.